# How can i place dynamic image view over texture view?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-textureview, dynamic-view

This is my camera preview layout and i have a dynamic image view to show the thumbnail.I am not able to place the image view overlaping the texture view.How to do this??

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/thumbnails"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">


    </LinearLayout>

    <TextureView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="453dp"
        android:id="@+id/textureView"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="59dp"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:id="@+id/videoButton"
        android:contentDescription="@string/video_button"
        android:src="@mipmap/start_recording"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom" />

    <Chronometer
        android:layout_width="129dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/chronometer"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:textColor="#ff0000"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="left|bottom" />

</FrameLayout>
```

This is my code for creating dynamic image view.

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.thumbnails);
bitMapIndex = 0;
if (layout.getChildCount() > 0) {
    layout.removeAllViews();
}
for (Bitmap eachBitMap : bitMapsAvailable) {    
    bitMapIndex++;
    ImageView thumb = new ImageView(this);
    thumb.setId(new Integer(bitMapIndex+ 17));
    thumb.setLayoutParams(new android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams(100, 80));
    thumb.setImageBitmap(eachBitMap);
    // Adds the view to the layout
    thumb.setOnClickListener(previewThumb(thumb));
    layout.addView(thumb);
}
```

Comment: i think you didn't get my question....i have to place that linear layout over textureview,because image view is getting created inside tht linear layout.

Comment: @user7328722 What exactly is the requirement??

Comment: @sJy the dynamic image view are getting created inside linear layout....bt i want to place the image view by overlaping the texture view.how can i do that??

Comment: Moving <TextureView> over <Linear Layout> is not working...and its correct as per the <ImageButton> and <Chronometer> it should work...but unfortunatly its not

Comment: @user7328722 you have given marginTop 80dp for TextureView. So it will be 80dp away from top . Your linearlayout is at top which is 0dp. So remove 80dp marginTop. Also put the LinearLayout below TextureView in XML.

Comment: did that help??

Comment: yeah...thanks it worked